# Como fazer com que a borda superior da div se sobreponha a ponta superior da borda direita?

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer com que a borda superior da `div` se sobreponha totalmente a ponta superior da borda da direita, mas não estou obtendo sucesso.

**html**

```
<div class="caixa"></div>
```

**css**

```
.caixa{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-top:14px solid red;
    border-right:14px solid blue;
}
```

Vejam no exemplo abaixo que as bordas no canto superior direito da div se encontram de forma diagonal, gostaria que a borda superior cobrisse totalmente o canto superior direito.

http://jsfiddle.net/zNkcV/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando pseudo-elemento `.caixa::after`, é possível obter o efeito desejado:

```
.caixa{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-top: 14px solid red;
position: relative;
```

}

```
.caixa::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; top: 0px; left: 0; right: 0;
    border-right: 14px solid blue;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zNkcV/1/)